# Using await from function returning JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have an async function that returns JSON:

```
async function test() {
    var answer = { "status": 0 };
    return answer;
}
```

**Case 1:** Calling it using await when the function is called results the following output:

```
var test_k = await test();
console.log(test_k);
```

Output: `{ status: 0 }`

**Case 2:** Calling it using await later on the returned variable results the following output:

```
var test_p = test();

await test_p;
console.log(test_p);
```

Output: `Promise { { status: 0 } }`

The output above are produced in `Node.js v12.18.3` environment.

In Case 1, I can access `test_k.status`. I can't do the same in Case 2. I need to access the JSON object in Case 2. How can I do that?

Comment: `test_p` is a Promise. Result of `await test_p` is the value You want: `console.log(await test_p);`.

Comment: `(await test_p).status;`

Comment: `await test_p;` will wait until `test_p` is resolved then return that value. Since you're doing nothing with it, it is thrown away and the code continues. Think of that line as if it's `new MyClass();` you get *something* back but it's never assigned or used, so it has no effect on the rest of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case 2 code should read:

```
var test_p = test();

var output = await test_p;
console.log(output);
```

awaiting the `test_p` promise doesn't change that promise, it will output the result for you to then assign to a variable, so you need to log that output, not just the original function/promise.